# Clustering column non-EQ relation

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Have a table

```
CREATE TABLE room (
    uuidhotel text,
    startreservetime double,
    endreservetime double,
    uuid text,
    uuidguest text,
    uuidroom text,
    PRIMARY KEY (uuidhotel, startreservetime, endreservetime)
```

query like this works:

```
select * from room WHERE uuidhotel = 'testUUIDHotel' and startreservetime > 1;
```

but when I try to use:

```
cqlsh:hotelier> select * from room WHERE uuidhotel = 'testUUIDHotel' and startreservetime > 1 and endreservetime < 3;
```

got an error.

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Clustering column "endreservetime" cannot be restricted (preceding column "startreservetime" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)
```

How can I execute query with 3 parameters ?

Any alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you want to use a greater/less-than operator on a PRIMARY KEY component in Cassandra, all of the preceding PRIMARY KEY components must be restricted with an equals operator.

So how can you query for a date range?  Well, you can specify the same PRIMARY KEY component *twice*.  Currently that doesn't help you.  But with a small modeling change (coupled with storing each row twice...once for the start and again for the end) it does:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM room WHERE uuidhotel = 'testUUIDHotel' 
  AND reservetime > 1 AND reservetime < 3;

 uuidhotel     | reservetime | startend | uuid                                 | uuidguest                            | uuidroom
---------------+-------------+----------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------
 testUUIDHotel |         2.1 |        S | 49c441cd-a6cd-4638-85b3-fdc3405779f4 | cd3ad747-42a3-4d31-b02a-8190dd8559d8 | daae89d5-abd3-4cac-b4cc-aec9d6b7fb1f
 testUUIDHotel |         2.2 |        E | 49c441cd-a6cd-4638-85b3-fdc3405779f4 | cd3ad747-42a3-4d31-b02a-8190dd8559d8 | daae89d5-abd3-4cac-b4cc-aec9d6b7fb1f

(2 rows)
```

Basically, if you store an entry for each the start and the end, (and use `startend` in your key for uniqueness) you'll be able to effectively query with greater/less-than on the time.  Just make sure you're querying with a wide-enough gap that you don't query in-between the range of `reservetime`s that you care about.

Comment: If you have a row with start time 2 and end time 10, it will also get selected.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The bottom line is that your models need to be built around your queries, and your queries need to be built around your business requirements.  So this may need to be adjusted based on that.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Apparently tuple comparisons don't work the way I thought they did... The below answer doesn't work, it compares the entire tuple and NOT the individual elements, i.e. `(1,2) < (3,1)` returns true. Leaving it in case it inspires a better method...**

Another approach, you can [query with non-EQ conditions on multiple clustering columns using tuples](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/select_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_d35_v2q_xj__slice-composites).

However, it would require you to have a single non-EQ operator, i.e. your query would have to look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (c1, c2) > (1, 3)
```

So you have to transform your values such that you can use a single operator. You can do this by negating both sides!

Remember from algebra:

```
5 < 10
```

If you negate both sides, you have to switch the operator:

```
-5 > -10
```

So create a new column `negative_c2` with the negated values from `c2` and do the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (c1, negative_c2) > (1, -3)
```